# How to display a SortedDictionary in DataGrid WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, sorteddictionary

I want to display a `sortedDictionary` in the `dataGrid` when the key is int and value is List of `ClassType` for example `value-List` of `Persons`.

For the example:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SortedDictionary<int, List<Person>> Sd1 = new SortedDictionary<int,List<Person>>();
        Person p1 = new Person("htryh");
        Person p2 = new Person("juyik");
        List<Person> PL = new List<Person>();
        PL.Add(p1);
        PL.Add(p2);
        Sd1.Add(1, PL);
        dt1.ItemsSource = Sd1;

    }
}
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

In the `dataGrid` in the column "`Key`" i see the int , but in the column "`value`" i see:
(Collection).
How do i solve this??
Thanks.

Comment: I want to see my Persons in every way and i don't know how to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set **`AutoGenerateColumns`** to **`False`** on dataGrid and provide your own set of columns.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dt1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Key" Binding="{Binding Key}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Value}"
                                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                                DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```